# Applying $\sum_i \partial_{x_i}$, $\sum_i x_i \partial_{x_i}$ and $\sum_i x_i^2 \partial_{x_i}$ to Schur polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials, schur-functions

The operators $L_k=\sum_i x_i^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, with integer $k$, take symmetric polynomials into symmetric polynomials.

Is it known how to write the result of the application of $L_0$, $L_1$ or $L_2$ to a Schur polynomial as a sum of Schur polynomials?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $x \, \partial_{x} \, x^k = k \, x^k$, the operator $L$ just records the total degree of a polynomial. For Schur (and Jack, Macdonald, $\dots$) polynomials it thus acts by $$L \, s_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_n) = |\lambda| \, s_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_n) \,,$$ where the eigenvalue $|\lambda|=\sum_i \lambda_i$ the weight of the partition $\lambda$.

The operator $L$ is well known. At the Jack level, in terms of Dunkl operators we have $L = \sum_i d_i$ (maybe up to a multiplicative factor), which is an element of the center of the degenerate affine Hecke algebra. At the Macdonald level, in terms of Cherednik--Dunkl operators we recognise the difference operator $q^L = Y_1 \cdots Y_n = D_n^n(x;q,t)$ as the $n$th Macdonald operator, which lies in the center of the affine Hecke algebra. Physically, $L = \mathrm{i} \sum_i \partial_{\xi_i}$ is interpreted as the total momentum operator (up to a factor of $\hbar$) in terms of the additive variables (coordinates of particles moving on the unit circle) defined via $x_i = e^{\mathrm{i}\, \xi_i}$.

Comment: Of course, how silly. But how about slightly more general operators like $L_0=\sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and $L_2=\sum_i x_i^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, that change the degree? Is something known about that?

Comment: @thedude $\sum_{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ applied to Schubert polynomials (which include Schur polynomials as a special case) are studied in https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00321.

Comment: @thedude see also Section 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.08329.pdf for more specific information about Schur polynomials

Comment: For the action of $\sum\limits_i \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ on skew Schur polynomials, see [Darij Grinberg, Nazar Korniichuk, Kostiantyn Molokanov, Severyn Khomych, *The diagonal derivative of a skew Schur polynomial*](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/Nabla-short.pdf). (We are about to post it on the arXiv tonight!)

Comment: The operator $L$ can be defined on any graded module (since it just sends each homogeneous element $f$ of degree $n$ to $nf$). If my memory does not fail me, I think it is called the "Euler derivation", though naming things after Euler is never a good way to disambiguate them.

Comment: Clearly the question as it is now is too simple. Would it be ok if I edited it to ask about the action of $\sum_i \partial_i$ and $\sum_i x_i^2\partial_i$?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, see the 'particle number operator' in Wikipedia.  Similarly, in umbral calculus, a generaliztion of the Euler operator $x\partial_x$ is $RL$, or state number operator, where $R$ is a raising / creation operator, i.e., $R \; \psi_n(x) = \psi_{n+1}(x)$ and $L$  a lowering / annihilation operator, i.e., $L \; \psi_n(x) = n \; \psi_{n-1}(x)$. Then $RL \; \psi_n(x) = n \; \psi_n(x)$. For the iconic Sheffer polynomial sequence $p_n(x) = x^n$, $R=x$ and $L = \partial_x$.

Comment: For the action of $\partial_{x_i}$ on the elementary Schur polynomials, see https://oeis.org/A130561( my Sept 07 2016 formulas).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, You'll also find the 'number operator' on pgs. 27 and 34 of "The Categorified Heisenberg Algebra I: A Combinatorial Representation" by Jeffrey C. Morton, Jamie Vicary (https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2054).

Answer (score 7):

The answer for $L_1=\sum_ix_i^2\partial_i$ can be derived in a rather straightforward way (I changed your convention a little bit to match the usual formulas for Virasoro algebra). Namely, use the determinantal definition of Schur function
$$
s_\lambda=\frac{a_{\lambda+\delta}}{a_{\delta}}=\frac{\det(x_j^{\lambda_i+n-i})}{\det(x_j^{n-i})}.
 $$
Indeed, since $L_1$ is a derivation, we have
$$
L_1\left(\frac{a_{\lambda+\delta}}{a_{\delta}}\right)=\frac{L_1(a_{\lambda+\delta})a_{\delta}-L_1(a_{\delta})a_{\lambda+\delta}}{a_{\delta}^2}=
\frac{L_1(a_{\lambda+\delta})}{a_{\delta}}-
\frac{L_1(a_{\delta})a_{\lambda+\delta}}{a_{\delta}^2}.
 $$
Moreover, $L_1(a_{\delta})=(n-1)e_1a_{\delta}$ since we can apply our derivation $L_1$ row by row, and almost each time we get a determinant with two equal rows, so only the derivation of row $1$ counts, and
$$
\frac{L_1(a_{\delta})a_{\lambda+\delta}}{a_{\delta}^2}=(n-1)e_1s_\lambda=
(n-1)\sum_{\square\in\mathrm{Ins}(\lambda)}s_{\lambda+\square}
 $$
thanks to the Pieri rule (here $\mathrm{Ins}(\lambda)$ are the places where boxes can be added to $\lambda$ to get a valid diagram, as in the [other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/464619/1306)). Similarly,
$$
L_1(a_{\lambda+\delta})=\sum_{\square\in\mathrm{Ins}(\lambda)}(\lambda_{i(\square)}+n-i(\square))a_{\lambda+\square}
 $$
(where, of course, $i(\square)$ is the number of the row of $\lambda$ where $\square\in\mathrm{Ins}(\lambda)$ is located) ,so
$$
\frac{L_1(a_{\lambda+\delta})}{a_{\delta}}=\sum_{\square\in\mathrm{Ins}(\lambda)}(\lambda_{i(\square)}+n-i(\square))s_{\lambda+\square},
 $$
and finally
$$
L_1\left(\frac{a_{\lambda+\delta}}{a_{\delta}}\right)=\sum_{\square\in\mathrm{Ins}(\lambda)}(\lambda_{i(\square)}-i(\square)+1)s_{\lambda+\square}
 $$

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Ins}$? The addable boxes?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: yes. This is the same notation in the formula conjectured in thedude's answer below.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Sam already answered but it is probably better to make the answer self-contained, so I'll add a definition now.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Jules Lamers considers $k=1$.

In the comments to that answer, people have mentioned that the case $k=0$ has been solved. Namely, for a given partition $\lambda$ let Del($\lambda$) be the set of boxes in its diagram that may be deleted and the result is still a diagram. Then
$$ L_0(s_\lambda)=\sum_{\square \in {\rm Del}(\lambda)} [c(\square)+N]s_{\lambda-\square},$$
where $N$ is the number of variables, $ c(\square)$ is the content of a box and $\lambda-\square$ is the diagram obtained from $\lambda$ upon deletion of that box.

I have done some experimentation, and I would like to propose a **conjecture** for the action of $L_2$ on a Schur polynomial.

Let Ins($\lambda$) be the set of boxes that may be inserted in its diagram and the result is still a diagram. Then I believe that
$$ L_2(s_\lambda)=\sum_{\square \in {\rm Ins}(\lambda)} c(\square)s_{\lambda+\square}.$$

For example, in the diagram for $(2,1)$ three boxes can be inserted, leading to either $(3,1)$, $(2,2)$ or $(2,1,1)$. In the first case the content of the inserted box is $2$, in the second case it is $0$ and in the third case it is $-2$. So $L_2(s_{(2,1)})=2s_{(3,1)}+0s_{(2,2)}-2s_{(2,1,1)}.$

I would be grateful if someone could prove this. Such a simple result cannot be too hard.

Comment: Have you thought about proving this by the commutators relating the $L_0$, $L_1$, and $L_2$ operators?

Comment: @SamHopkins No, I haven't, I am not an expert and won't even try to prove it

Comment: Because of the commutator relation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} x_i - x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = \mathrm{id}$, we have $L_0L_2 - L_2L_0 = 2 L_1$. Probably there is a "representation of the Virasoro algebra" or similar fancy thing lurking here. But anyways I bet this identity is enough to prove your conjectured formula for $L_2(s_{\lambda})$.

Comment: @SamHopkins, the $sl_2$ algebra suffices for $z^{n+1}\partial_z$ for $n =-1,0,1$ (see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/is-there-a-formula-similar-to-fxa-ea-fracddxfx-to-express-f-al/126744#126744).

Comment: @SamHopkins Or, a little more generally than $sl_2$ but still less fancy than Virasoro: the Heisenberg algebra